# How can a demon hide the true nature of its biology?

Tags: science-based, biology, demons

This is a follow up question to this:

[How can an unholy Trinity to be worshipped as one being?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/168693/how-can-an-unholy-trinity-to-be-worshipped-as-one-being)

The god Zoth-Ommog has been reincarnated into the world as a small child. As he grows, he will gain access to more of his power. Until such a time, he will slowly build his ministry with the help of his cult, who raise him after his mother's death. Currently however, he doesn't have access to his full power due to him being a kid. There are others who wish to stop this plan, and kill the child before any of the apocalyptic shennigans begins. To accomplish this, government forces have spent time and money to locate it.

The child may appear completely human on the outside. However, it technically has no human parents. It has no Father, as it is a reincarnated form of a god. It has no real mother, as she was simply a vessel for the demon's power. Therefore, it has no DNA or any identifiable way to prove that it is human. When these tests are done, it should show that this child is not normal at all and expose it to the authorities.

I need a way for Zoth-Ommog's biology to hide the fact that it isn't human to avoid raising suspicions about him. How can I make this possible?

Comment: Can there be any divinely powered mechanics behind these things?  That is to say, can we count "God Magic" as a reason... or does this all have to scientifically be linked.

Comment: This is one strange question. Gods do miracles; that is what they do. A god who could not miraculously alter the results of mundane tests performed by mere mortals would be a rather impotent god, not worthy of the worship and adoration. Consider, for example, the Christian Triune God; in His hypostasis as God the Son, He famously converted water into wine, and in industrial quantities; how did He do it? He *willed* it to be so. Zoth-Ommog Jr. can simply *will* the samples taken by the scientists to test human. No further explanation is necessary, and would only *diminish* the mystery.

Comment: I would automatically assume that a body created by a god, would be indistinguishable from a body created through procreation.

Comment: If a spiritual being is even capable of siring children with humans, why would we expect those children's DNA to show anything other than typical humanity? Will there be little floaty pieces of ectoplasm in the chromosomes filling in codon gaps? I wouldn't expect any deviation from the norm except for those qualities that would be important to the deity.

Comment: The child Zoth-Ommog is fully human. Presumably as he grows older he acquire increasing amounts of supernatural power and at that, possibly, undergo biological changes to become more demonic. No need to overthink it..

Comment: I don't see how this query is story based. The OP could delete the whole (unnecessary) M.P. business, or at least severely edit that paragraph, and still end up with the same non-story-based query.  At this point, I don't think I need to say *obviously it's opinion based to some degree* -- that's what we deal with in the art of worldbuilding! But can someone explain how supernatural, preternatural or ordinarly natural functions of biology are being seen as story based.  I'd vote to keep open.

Comment: Why cannot you use the normal solutions of escaping beyond the search area or faking your death so they are forced to spend less resources? Or both. Or faking you have escaped beyond the search area so they will spend the resources to get access to where they think you are.

Comment: See "Good Omens" by Terry Pratchett & Neil Gaiman.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on what constitutes its incarnation (I say this because it may not be proper reincarnation proper). of which, there might be two kinds.

The first type of incarnation is simply Zoth-Ommog with the form of a human child. Beneath the appearance of a human being it is all demonic deity. This being, probably, won't even have what passes for DNA, let alone any other bodily fluids. Any attempt at a DNA or almost any other medical test will unmask its demonic nature. This would be a bad choice for a dark deity.

The second type of incarnation is much safer and a thinking person would consider this the incarnation of choice for demon deity bent on a becoming the Dark Messiah.

This incarnation will be in the form of a normal human being. Hey! What a cute kid! It will be constituted like a natural biological entity. This includes having DNA in its cells. However, it will need somewhere to store that necessary genetic information when has to assume its full demonic manifestation during adulthood. Fortunately, just the thing already exists.

A large of DNA is so-called [junk DNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-coding_DNA); also, called non-coding DNA. This is DNA without any apparent function. Some scientists believe it is remnant viral DNA left over from contact with human hosts in previous generations. Whatever it is it's the ideal repository for the necessary genetic information to enable what appears to be a mere human being into a fully fledged demonic entity.

So how can Zoth-Ommog hide his demonic biology and evade being discovered by a DNA test? By concealing it as part of his junk or non-coding DNA.

Comment: Hide it in plain sight --- I like that approach!

Comment: @elemtilas Sometimes it's easy to overlook the obvious. Junk DNA must be good for something.

Answer (score 1):

**Zoth is *Adorable*.** *squeeee!!!*

What woman isn't instantly turned into a fountain of burbles and gurgles at the mere sight of him?

Even the most severe, anti-motherly, etc... woman simply can't condone collecting a blood sample, hair, or skin. It would be an utter travesty to even attempt to do so. It is so unconscionable they will fudge the collection/results.

Any man instantly wants to avoid it at all costs. Simply looking at Zoth is sufficient reason to have an army of women dragging their personal life over the coals on national TV. And no man wants that... Even the more daring, social outcasts take one look and instantly go and sweet talk a woman into taking the necessary sample. They don't care if that happens to be adult skin they collect, admitting otherwise would simply paint them as the most spineless man on the planet.

**Zoth is *Silver Tongued*!**

No mater what the situation, no mater how horrendous the implication, no mater the stalwart integrity of the witness, a story comes forth. It is perfectly imperfect, the details are there, the other version of events (even from enemies) match in all the right ways, even the results of tests have perfectly reasonable explanations. Even when new evidence comes to light, it only serves to bolster Zoth's version of events.

Everything roles of Zoth leaving the metaphorical smell of roses.

**Zoth is *Talented*!**

He holds the under 14 year old championship in chess, kick boxing, rock climbing, and has already written a paper on chemistry. A Prodigy on the fast track in the sciences/engineering/medicine with a talent for discovering "advances" while holding the bleeding heart of a corpse found halfway across the city, with the associated paperwork that makes it 100% legal.

Sure the authorities know something is up with him... Its just that a few adorable quirks are *perfectly fine* in such a young individual! After all the patent on dynamic blood transmogrification is worth billions... A few million to get the paperwork sorted out is just chump change.

Answer (score 1):

### Implant a Tube of Blood

So this is from [the real life case of John Schneeberger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Schneeberger)

> He implanted a 15 cm Penrose drain filled with another man's blood
>   and anticoagulants in his arm. During tests, he tricked the laboratory
>   technician into taking the blood sample from the place the tube was
>   planted.

This worked for several years before he was caught. There's no reason, your demon couldn't copy this same technique.

Any other test your government runs, the demon prepares for, so he'll pass. Similar to the movie Gattaca. He probably has a human locked in his basement he keeps alive so all his blood, urine, and skin samples match.